# Clone Ubuntu Machine

Tags: backup

I have an install of Ubuntu Maverick on slicehost, that I'd like to replicate on a different machine (a kvm VM install).

Is there a simple way of mirroring all it? I mainly care about installed programs, installations, mysql + postgres config/data.

okay.. so I guess I mainly care about everything.  maybe except for network config, which I can fix easily enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/) is a free and open source program for Debian, Ubuntu-based, or derivative software systems that can:

- Create a customized Live CD/DVD (a remaster) of Debian and its derivatives.
- Back up an entire system, including user data, to an installable Live CD/DVD.

Comment: It's really only a matter of time before this link is dead. Could you reproduce the gist of it here? (with proper attribution of course. )

Comment: Looks like this is the main project page. If it goes dead, then either the project is gone, or it has moved to somewhere else, and google will help to find it.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used SliceHost, but the following should work with any hosting provider that grants you full root access over SSH to your hosted machine.

Basically, use [rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/rsync) in "archive" mode.

1. Create the file/partition/LVM logical volume large enough to contain all the files from your remote VM.  Format it and mount on `/mnt`.
2. Run rsync:

   ```
   rsync -a -z -A -X -e ssh --inplace --progress root@remotehost:/ /mnt/
   ```

You might want to add a `-n` to the rsync invcation to test it before doing the transfer.

If you don't have any POSIX ACLs or extended attributes in the remote VM, you can leave out the `-A` or `-X` options respectively.  If you have any hard-links on the remote VM, you must add a `-H` option.

Comment: Well, I was looking for something more aware of the OS.  I know I can use rsync/rdiff-backup and exclude sys proc tmp and such.. but that's not very clean, and works better for backups IMO, then cloning a full machine.

Answer (score 1):

***[Systemback](http://www.unixmen.com/systemback-restore-linux-system-previous-state/)*** is a better then Windows Restore like program that can make live USB copy in a very simple way, no terminal needed. Also restoring from Live USB or on fresh install is also posible. It takes about 2-3min to make full backup of the system and can be scheduled at will. Works perfect under Ubuntu 14.04

[image]