# how to create recovery DVD?

Tags: data-recovery, dvd

I have brought Dell vostro 2520. It has preinstalled ubuntu.
Can you please tell to how to create recovery disk?
So that after format, I can reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/206071/make-recovery-disk-for-customers

Comment: That is not how Linux/Ubuntu works; what you used for installation is your re-installation media and what you use to format. Personal files you save by making backups.

Comment: @Rinzwind that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Live DVD or USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), which you can use to reinstall Ubuntu. It also comes with a full desktop you can run right from the boot media and install tools to recover your system with. You can choose to reinstall Ubuntu keeping files, programs, and settings, as an option.