# Make a snapshot of Ubuntu for future installs

Tags: iso, clone

When we install Ubuntu, we get a lot of softwares pre-installed. Just like this, is it possible for me to install Ubuntu, then install all my required softwares and packages, setup my desktop and other system wide settings and once I get my perfect Ubuntu ready for use; I make snapshot or installable (my own Ubuntu version) of the system into a DVD or ISO. So that in future, I can just install Ubuntu through that ISO and get everything ready in a moment!

I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8125/clone-ubuntu-machine), but remastersys is no longer available. I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) as well, but it's too long and doesn't seem to be what I need.

Any other solution?

Comment: No answer yet??

Answer (score 0):

```
genisoimage -o /media/cdrom/imagename.iso /
```

Operating system images are best created offline.  To do this use software like
[hiren's boot cd](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)
(includes tons of other very useful/harmful tools), k3b, brasero, partimage, etc.  This is a cross-platform solution as well.

[mkisofs](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/07/31/how-to-create-custom-linux-iso-image/) is another option but doesn't seem legit to me, not having a manual page.

Credit: http://tuxarena.blogspot.com/2009/03/4-ways-to-create-cddvd-iso-images-in.html; 
 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/using-genisoimage-to-make-an-iso-of-a-live-system-627559/